# Regex to split coordinates string Java

Tags: java, arrays, regex, arraylist, coordinates

I have the following String:

```
["lat\/lng: (49.47491213070514,-1.2361999005079265)","lat\/lng (42.478589638625664,-1.226332724094391)"]
```

I'd like to split this using regex so I can enter the latLng data into an array.

Is there an expression so that I can grab the data that's just inbetween the brackets?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse JSON, use a JSON parser.  It will be much easier to maintain and less confusing for whoever has to maintain the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
\(([\.\-0-9]+)\,([\.\-0-9]+)\)
```

when performed on each string in that array individually will give you back match groups with those values separated. I don't know how to implement in Java though!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this seems to be grabbing everything except the content in between the brackets though?

Comment: I misunderstood that you would be processing the array as a string, not an array. Anyway, someone else gave you something more useful in full code! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex, `(?<=\()[^)]*(?=\))`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Test
        String str = "[\"lat\\/lng: (49.47491213070514,-1.2361999005079265)\",\"lat\\/lng (42.478589638625664,-1.226332724094391)\"]";

        String[][] arr = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\()[^)]*(?=\\))")
                                .matcher(str)
                                .results()
                                .map(MatchResult::group)
                                .map(s -> s.split(","))
                                .toArray(String[][]::new);

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[[49.47491213070514, -1.2361999005079265], [42.478589638625664, -1.226332724094391]]
```

<kbd>[ONLINE DEMO](https://ideone.com/JJJL6F)</kbd>

**Non-Stream solution:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Test
        String str = "[\"lat\\/lng: (49.47491213070514,-1.2361999005079265)\",\"lat\\/lng (42.478589638625664,-1.226332724094391)\"]";

        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\()[^)]*(?=\\))").matcher(str);

        List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

        while (matcher.find()) {
            list.add(matcher.group().split(","));
        }

        String[][] arr = list.toArray(new String[0][0]);

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
    }
}
```

<kbd>[ONLINE DEMO](https://ideone.com/4WKPZ3)</kbd>

**Explanation of the regex at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gPF8BV/1):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I seem to be getting a couple of errors with this though, 1: cannot resolve method results in Matcher
2: reference to group is ambiguous, could be either group() or group(int)
Edit a 3rd error: cannot resolve method split(Java.lang.string)

Comment: @Jonwil - Probably, your JDK version is below 9. [Matcher#result](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results()) was added in Java9. Anyway, I've just added a non-Stream solution. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Answer (score 1):

Java regex supports capture groups `(` `)` ...

assuming the pattern provided by @somewhatsapient is correct:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\(([\.\-0-9]+)\,([\.\-0-9]+)\)");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(inputString);
if(m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

Since it delivers what is asked for, one can save on mapping and splitting the result altogether.
And when casting it ...that's rather `double` (usable) than `String` (useless); for example:

```
new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(m.group(1)), Double.parseDouble(m.group(2)))
```

Regex might not even be the most elegant way to do it - since one can auto-map an `ArrayList<LatLng>` with GSON converter.

Comment: The first line will result in a compilation error. `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the head and tail, then split on what’s between terms.

```
String[] latLngs = str.replaceAll("^.*\\(|\\).*$", "").split("\\).*?\\(");
```